# How to quit Trim Enabler?

Tags: macos, trim

I just updated Trim Enabler after updating my Mac to OS X 10.8.5. The new version doesn't have a quit button, option or anything like that. How do I close it? I cannot remove it from the menu bar by dragging it. What can I do, short of rebooting?

[image: Trim Enabler in system tray]

Comment: You mean you want to close that window!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can **press <kbd>⌘ cmd</kbd> + <kbd>Q</kbd> when the app (actually, the menu) is opened**, according to an official answer from [this blog post](http://www.groths.org/trim-enabler-3-0-released/).

Comment: Interestingly, this actually works!

Answer (score 1):

You can use AppleScript to send the application a quit Apple event:

```
osascript -e 'quit app "Trim Enabler"'
```

Quit Apple events are also used by loginwindow to quit non-Cocoa applications when you log out.

If that doesn't work, `killall Trim\ Enabler` is probably also safe. It sends the process a TERM signal, which usually allows a process to terminate cleanly.